# Multiplication of Array Elements inside a loop

Tags: arrays, linux, bash, shell

Here's the problem: i've this loop that sum elements array and it works:

```
for ((i=0: i<$n; i++));
do
ris=$(($ris+${array[$i]}))
done
```

Now I want to do the same thing but using * operator instead + in order to obtain the moltiplication between the array elements:

```
for ((i=0: i<$n; i++));
do
ris=$(($ris*${array[$i]}))
done
```

But in this case I get this error:

> syntax error in expression (error token is "*3")

Where's the problem?

Comment: What's the content of `array`? Also, remember to initialize `ris` to 1 if multiplying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your first iteration, `ris` is empty, but

```
ris=$(($ris+${array[$i]}))
```

expands to

```
ris=$((+${array[$i]}))
```

what is still valid.
That doesn't happen with * operator, so you should initialize $ris to 1 (not 0, obviously)

```
ris=$((*${array[$i]}))
```

Comment: thx!! the error was that ris was not initialize to 1!!

and what about division? If i use / instead of * the loop give me the moltiplication...

Comment: There is a small thing with division. `bash` does not deal with floating point. I cannot see the sense for a running division, but if it make sense for you, you should initialize `$ris` with an enough high integer, or perform a running multiplication and print 1/`$ris`